# Jenkins UCM ClearCase plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, clearcase-ucm

Is it possible to use the Jenkins UCM clearcase plugin with existing view either snapshot or dynamic view without creating a view with each build request.  Is there another way to achieve this?  Thank you for all replies.

Answer (score 0):

The [Jenkins ClearCase UCM plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin) mentions:

> The plugin will automatically create a snapshot view in a folder named 'view' in the root of the job's workspace
>
> We us a separate view per job, per client, **which allows us to reuse views in a context the only changes very little between builds**.
>
> The plugin creates a separate read/only development stream and snapshot view for every self polling job on every slave that executes the job.
> **The stream and view is created the first time the job is executed on the slave and then reused by successive job executions**.

That means it does not create a different view per build, but reuse the current one.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I don't want to create a new snapshot view.  How do I re-use an existing snapshot view or dynamic view.  There are bunch of permission and domain user issue that I have to overcome in order to run jenkins creating the view.  Is there a work around just to re-use an existing view.  Please let me know.

Comment: @learn_allot I don't know of a way to reuse a ClearCase view in a CI environment like Jenkins. What I used to do is to create a git repo in a ClearCase view, add and commit and push to a git repo accessible by Jenkins, and then use that remote repo with a Jenkins Git plugin. That is usually easier than trying to use ClearCase views.

Comment: I cannot use git repo that option is a no-go.  I use source code management as none and run the build using ant script. The questions is how do I trigger a build if a new baseline is created in clearcase ucm stream. I cannot use any of the clearcase plug-in since all the existing plug-in will create a view.  I don't want jenkins to create a view during a build.  Any or all suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: @learn_allot "Any or all suggestions will be appreciated" Then you need some pulling script which will monitor ClearCase for new baseline and, when detected, will change a non-UCM config spec of a unique view used by a Jenkins job (with Jenkins ClearCase plugin, not ClearCase UCM plugin)

Comment: Another question - If I use a source code management of None.  Just invoke ant script to do the build without using ClearCase plugin.  How can I re-configure the Jenkins workspace to reference the dynamic view M drive path? Currently I am aware that I can create a snap-shot view in the jenkins workspace but I want to use dynamic view in the M drive.  Thank you.

Comment: @learn_allot if the dynamic view is started, then its path would be `m:\<viewtag>`. In a "None" source code management, you could use that path.

Comment: i get an error.  Building in workspace m:\viewtag.  Fatal:  unable to find build script m:\viewtag\build\build.xml

Comment: @learn_allot you need to make sure a vob is mounted as well: `m:\viewtag\avob`: nothing can be written directly in a view. Of course, I assume you have replace `viewtag` by an actual view tag.

Comment: Just to elaborate what I am doing.  I have the vob mounted.  I can access the directory through windows M drive.  Yes - I am replacing the viewtag with my own view tag.  I have m:\view tag\prod\build\build.xml.  In the use custom workspace I have m:\viewtag.  In invoke ANT i have m:\view tag\prod\build\build.xml.  I am getting unable to find m:\view tag\prod\build\build.xml

Comment: @learn_allot make sure the Jenkins slave service which is executing that job is running with the same account as the one you are using (successfully) to access that view content.